# native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.",

Tags: android, react-native

Although it has exits on my project but i trying run and build it show this problem , my project copy from another person before him leave this work
full list :

> [{
> "resource": "/C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/zzz/appsuachuabinhduongmain/android/",
> "owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#3",
> "code": "0",
> "severity": 8,
> "message": "Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip'.\r\nSettings file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\zzz\appsuachuabinhduongmain\android\settings.gradle' line: 14\r\nA problem occurred evaluating settings 'appsuachuabinhduong'.\r\nCould not read script 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\zzz\appsuachuabinhduongmain\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.",
> "source": "Java",
> "startLineNumber": 1,
> "startColumn": 1,
> "endLineNumber": 1,
> "endColumn": 1
> }]

i trying delete node moudle i install but i don't work